# Cufon, jquery text repacement

Tags: jquery, cufon

I'm using cufon text replacing from Jquery 
https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/styling

but I have a problem:

I have something like this

```
<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>
    item2
    <ul><li>itemSec1</li></ul>
</li>
```

I applied cufon for  "ul li " but i don't want  to use cufon for "ul li ul li",

```
Cufon.replace('ul li');
```

Can I stop cufon for that one ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The only way that you can do this currently (without modifying the `Cufon.replace` method) is to add a class to the `<ul>`s you want do do replacement on.  That way you can do this:

```
Cufon.replace('ul.use_cufon_class>li');
```

Which should get you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Cufon.replace('ul > li');
```

i think `:only-child` will fail http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/onlyChild

Comment: Correct, `:only-child` selects an element only if it is an *only child* of the parent element (i.e. there are no other elements descended from it.) **See:** (New documentation) http://api.jquery.com/only-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

One possible selector to avoid adding class for the UL, if you know where ULs are used:

```
Cufon.replace('#something > ul > li');
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:(tested)

Cufon.replace('ul:has(ul) > li  a');

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but:

```
Cufon.replace('ul>li:only-child');
```